# Is $_SESSION safe from sql injects?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use PDO to access my MySQL database, and want to use IN. But sadly it don't seam to work with prepare, so I wrote this function

```
function is_numeric_array($array){
    if(!is_array($array))
        return is_numeric($array);

    if(is_array($array))
        foreach($array as $int)
            if(!is_numeric($int))
                return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then used it like this

```
    if(!is_numeric_array($_SESSION['story'])){
        die("Error, array contains non-integers");
    }

    $query = "(";
    for($i = 0; $i<count($_SESSION['story']); $i++)
        $query .= $_SESSION['story'][$i].(count($_SESSION['story'])-1 != $i ? "," : "");
    $query .= ")";

    //Collect all data needed
    $stories = openConnection() -> query("SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE `id` IN {$query}") -> fetchAll();
```

I know it, looks ugly. But I don't want any SQL injects.

Comment: Why not build the IN clause of your statement with a series of ?, one for each entry in the array, then you can still use bind variables from the values in your array to make statements with an IN

Comment: Suggestion: use braces around your conditionals and loops.  You'll run into trouble eventually

Comment: It depends on where the $_SESSION variable comes from. If it can only be set by you, then it could be ok, but if there's any user input involved at all it is insecure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really have to test for the input being numeric, because in MySQL, any string e.g. `'123abc'` in a numeric context (like being compared to an integer column `id`) implicitly takes only the digits and ignores the rest. A non-numeric string like `'abc'` simply has the integer value 0 because there are no leading digits.

The point is, values are safe from SQL injection if you use query parameters. Whether the inputs come from $_SESSION or another source is irrelevant. $_SESSION is neither safe or unsafe with respect to SQL injection, it's how you pass the data to your query that matters.

I would also simplify the code to format the list of parameter placeholders:

```
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(1, count((array)$_SESSION['story']), '?'));
```

And forget about bindParam(), just pass the array to `execute()`.

```
//Collect all data needed
$storyQuery = openConnection() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `stories` 
    WHERE `id` IN ({$placeholders})");
$storyQuery -> execute((array)$_SESSION['story']);
$story = $storyQuery -> fetchAll();
```

---

Re your comment:

In PDO, you can use either named parameters like `:id`, or you can use positional parameters, which are always `?` (but don't mix these two types in a given query, use one or the other).

Passing an array to `execute()` automatically binds the array elements to the parameters. A simple array (i.e. indexed by integers) is easy to bind to positional parameters.

If you use named parameters, you must pass an associative array where the keys of the array match the parameter names. The array keys may optionally be prefixed with `:` but it's not required.

If you're new to PDO, it really pays to read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). There are code examples and everything!

Comment: That one looks a lot cleaner, but the are two things I don't understand. It's the `?` and why the `(array)$_SESSION['story']` is in the execute. (I'm new to PDO)

Comment: Now I understand, it just makes the array to `?,?,?` and then on execute it takes an array and fill in those values, correct?

Comment: Yep, and it guarantees to create the right number of `?` placeholders because I used `count()` of the array.

Comment: Thanks so much. The problem with me is that reading isn't my way of learning. But I'll take a look.

Comment: That must make it really hard to be in this career.

Comment: Kind of, I use youtube for some stuff, and other I just trial an error.

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION is just a way to store data on server over a session. It's not direct related with SQL injection.

Comment: So if I change this line `$_SESSION['story'][] = $_POST['action'];` it would be safe to use?

Comment: @Yemto I think the point is that it doesn't matter how you are retrieving the data you want to store (from memory, a constant, session data, user input) its how you pass it to your database query that matters.

Comment: Yes, it is. You must check length. Session is limited as storage space.

Answer (score -2):

Even if it's a cookie or a session , the hash that I store is alphanumeric only, for security purposes. When I'm checking the cookie/session against any type of inject / modification , I use [ctype_alnum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php):

```
if (ctype_alnum($_SESSION['value']))
    // exec code
else 
   // trigger_error
```

This way, no matter who is setting the SESSION value (you or the client, if you give him the possibility to), there wont be any case in which non-alphanumeric chars like  `comma`, `quotes`, `double quotes` or whatever will be inserted.