# Dynamic JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

Let's say I have a query -

```
Create Temporary Table myparams AS (
SELECT 'xyz' AS Column1
);

SELECT * FROM MyTable x
JOIN myparams y ON x.Column1 = y.Column1
```

This works perfectly. However, lets say I do this:

```
Create Temporary Table myparams AS (
SELECT NULL AS Column1
);
```

What I want to do here is that when there is `NULL` in `params`, I want to return all rows when I join on `MyTable`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * From MyTable x
IF(myparams.Column1 IS NULL, LEFT JOIN myparams.Column1 = x.Column1, 
INNER JOIN myparams.Column1 = x.Column1)
```

I am asking this as I have a stored procedure that takes parameters which can have value or `NULL` and I don't want to use `find_in_set` as it evaluates row by row which is inefficient while working with huge amount of data.

Editing the question since I was not clear about the `params` table. The input parameters can be comma separated text. So there is not one single value for parameter.

For ex -

```
Input params - `000-0000`, 1111-2222`

So currently I do this:

SELECT * FROM MyTable
find_in_set(MyTable.Column1, InputParams)
```

This evaluates each and every row which is very inefficient for 25 M rows.

I was rather thinking to create a temp table with all input params and then join on `MyTable`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` alone does exactly the same. If there is a match or not, it will still fetch u the left side table.

Comment: No not that. I don't always need full left table. If there is a value instead a `NULL` then it should pull just that from `MyTable` if nothing exists then it should return empty set

Comment: Then I don't know why you're using a temp table or a join at all. Just use `SELECT * FROM MyTable x WHERE x.Column1 = ?` and give it the procedure argument. If that argument is NULL, it'll return empty set because nothing is equal to NULL, not even another NULL.

Comment: If you have some other behavior in mind, you need to edit your question above and show some sample data and what you want the result to be. It's not clear from your question so far.

Comment: @BillKarwin The input can be comma separated text. Like 5 Hash Keys.

Comment: I would forget about using a stored procedure. Instead, write application code to make a dynamic SQL query with an `IN (...)` predicate, and inject one parameter for each element in your comma-separated list. See an example in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941328/20860

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH myparams AS (
SELECT null AS Column1
)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable x
INNER JOIN myparams y 
     ON x.Column1 IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(y.Column1,','))
          OR y.Column1 IS NULL
```

Above returns all values of table 'MyTable', and next query only those where Column1 is 'a' or 'b'

```
WITH myparams AS (
SELECT 'a,b' AS Column1
)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable x
INNER JOIN myparams y 
     ON x.Column1 IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(y.Column1,','))
          OR y.Column1 IS NULL
```

and a third option:

```
WITH myparams AS (
SELECT 'a,b' AS Column1
)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable x
INNER JOIN myparams y 
     ON x.Column1 = (SELECT value 
                     FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT ISNULL(Column1,'') 
                                        FROM myparams),',') 
                     WHERE value=x.Column1)
          OR (SELECT top 1 value 
              FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT ISNULL(Column1,'') 
                                 FROM myparams),',')) = ''
```

I do not have a large dataset, but this third option should be best in performance.

Comment: Edited the question. The params can be comma separated input

Comment: Edited my answer to work with a comma separated list.